# Ubuntu based docker-machine image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, boot2docker

Is there a possibility to simply create a docker-machine that is non-boot2docker based (i.e., Ubuntu based) (which uses virtualbox driver)?

I would like to have full-featured Linux distro running the docker daemon on my mac instead of Tiny Core Linux distro which is fast and lightweight but doesn't offer me all the debugging facilities I need.

I know I can create it manually. I'm just wondering if there is a simple way such as `docker-machine create` is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take advantage of the `--virtualbox-boot2docker-url` option.
[This issue](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/issues/372) illustrates its usage (with an iso which is *not* a TinyCore one, but a [RancherOS one](http://rancher.com/rancher-os/))

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-boot2docker-url https://releases.rancher.com/os/latest/machine-rancheros.iso rancher
```

---

If RancherOS is a bit too bare, you can take some clues from [how boot2docker is currently built](https://hub.docker.com/r/boot2docker/boot2docker/~/dockerfile/), and build your own distro.

The key is to remove the parts not needed in order to be able to launch headless VM without using too much memory.

```
# Remove useless kernel modules, based on unclejack/debian2docker 
RUN cd $ROOTFS/lib/modules && \
rm -rf ./*/kernel/sound/* && \
rm -rf ./*/kernel/drivers/gpu/* && \
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but RancherOS is still quite minimal. A good direction though...

Comment: @StepanVavra OK. I have edited the answer to include an laternative approach

Comment: is there anyway a prepared ubuntu iso available anywhere?